# How to set ylim for a xyplot of a zoo object (lattice)

Tags: r, lattice, zoo

I have a zoo object that looks like this:

```
z <- structure(c(6, 11, 3.6, 8.4, 8.9, 0, NA, 0.5, 7, NA, 9, NA),
    .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2234", "2234.1")), index = structure(c(-17746, -17745, -17744, -17743, -17742, -17741), class = "Date"),
    class = "zoo")
```

I tried to use lattice to plot both columns at the same time in 2 different panels:
`xyplot(z)`

This gives me the same x axis for both panels but different ylim. I want them to have the same ylim so I tried `xyplot(z, ylim=range(z[,1]))` it didn't do anything, so after reading "Plot zoo Series with Lattice" I tried `trellis.focus("panel", 2,1,ylim=range(z[,1]))` also without any luck...

This is probably an easy thing to do but I am finding the lattice package very hard to use (at least to start with). Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: please use `dput(head(z))` to provide example data

Comment: > dput(head(z)):structure(c(6, 11, 3.6, 8.4, 8.9, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("2234", "2234.1")), index = structure(c(-17746, 
-17745, -17744, -17743, -17742, -17741), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")

Comment: Ok. I think I know where the problem is. You got `NA` in your data and `range` need to handle it so you need to do `range(z, na.rm=TRUE)` (see my edited answer).

Comment: I glad I help. For future reference: you could edit your question instead of adding thing in comment. I do it for you (I changed data a little cause second column was all `NA`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `xyplot(z, ylim=range(z, na.rm=TRUE))`.

There are two things:

1. `na.rm=TRUE` cause `range` to work properly
2. `range(z)` instead of `range(z[,1])` let you handling range of all data, not just one column.

```
require(lattice)
require(zoo)
z <- zoo(cbind(a=1:4,b=11:14), Sys.Date()+(1:4)*10)
xyplot(z, ylim=range(z, na.rm=TRUE))
```

[image: It works]

Note: R version 2.13.0, zoo_1.6-5, lattice_0.19-26

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I was overcomplicating  :)

Answer (score 2):

`xyplot.zoo` accepts most `xyplot` arguments so:

```
xyplot(z, scales = list(y = list(relation = "same")))
```

or this variation:

```
xyplot(z, scales = list(y = list(relation = "same", alternating = FALSE)))
```

Comment: Did you notice that my solution placed y-ticks on left side of each panel and your on left first panel, on right second?

Comment: @Marek, I have added a variation which puts them all on the left.

Comment: Grothendieck Nice. I like this simplicity of syntax in lattice.